# Adding UIView dynamically to cells in UICollectionView only works for the first cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uikit

In the code below, the goal is to dynamically add a UIView to each UICollectionViewCell. However, the UIView only gets added to the first cell.

Printing the UICollectionViewCell frame shows that the frame is correct when `doInit` gets called, so how come the code only works for the first cell?

UICollectionView code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // Get cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(PantryStyleCellIdentifer, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PantryStyleCell

    // Get style & init cell
    let style = pantry[indexPath.row]
    cell.doInit(style)

    // Return cell
    return cell
}
```

UICollectionViewCell code:

```
class PantryStyleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var _style : BlockStyle?

    func doInit(style: BlockStyle) {
        // Store vars
        _style = style

        let testView = UIView(frame: frame)
        testView.backgroundColor = gGreenColor
        addSubview(testView)
    }
```

Comment: maybe you should subview it in self.contentView. Don't know what's  wrong. Actually you shouldn't do that because, when reusing the view again, there will be 2 testViews,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the view's `frame` as `self.frame`, you should put it as bounds.

```
let testView = UIView(frame: bounds)
```